# Nexus 5x Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm working on a VR app on Android with the Cardboard SDK.

But since I've updated my Nexus 5X to Android 7.1.1, I can't run my app anymore...

I get this error message: `AndroidNCompat: VR mode is not supported on this N device.` I think that it wants to run in Daydream mode, but since the Nexus 5X isn't compatible with it, it crashes...

So my question is, is it possible to force usage of the Cardboard instead of Daydream ?

Thank you for your help...